# Display A Success Message In Modal Box After Submit A Submit button In Asp,.net Used Bootstrap 5 Modal Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a login form. What happens is when you click to submit it will redirect you to another page (new one) what I would like to have is to show/display the different success messages within the modal right after clicking the button.

**HTML:**

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 text-center">Log In</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
          <label for="email" class="form-label">Email:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="lemail" runat="server" cssclass="form-control" TextMode="email" ToolTip="Enter Your Email ID"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Your Email ID" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="lemail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email ID" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="lemail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="pwd" class="form-label">Password:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="lpwd" runat="server" cssclass="form-control" TextMode="password" ToolTip="Enter Your Password"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Your Password" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="lpwd"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <asp:Button ID="lsubmit" runat="server" Text="Log In" cssclass="btn btn-danger mx-auto" OnClick="lsubmit_Click"/>
          <asp:Label ID="lstatus" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**C#**:

```csharp
protected void lsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
  if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) {
    con.Open();
  }
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.login");
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  sda.Fill(dt);
  int RowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
  for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++) {
    String Name = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
    String Email = dt.Rows[i]["Email_ID"].ToString();
    String Password = dt.Rows[i]["Password"].ToString();
    String Status = dt.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString();
    if (Email == lemail.Text && Password == lpwd.Text) {
      if (Status == "Approved") {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UpdateMessage", "<script> alert('"
          loginSuccessful "') </script>");
        Session["Name"] = Name;
        if (dt.Rows[i]["Role"].ToString() == "Admin")
          Response.Redirect("~/WebPage/Admin.aspx");
        else if (dt.Rows[i]["Role"].ToString() == "Pilot")
          Response.Redirect("~/WebPage/Pilot.aspx");
        else if (dt.Rows[i]["Role"].ToString() == "Staff")
          Response.Redirect("~/WebPage/Staff.aspx");
      } else if (Status == "Rejected") {
        lstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lstatus.Text = "Your Login ID Was Rejected By Admin";
      } else if (Status == "Pending") {
        lstatus.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
        lstatus.Text = "Your Login ID Is Pending";
      }
    } else {
      lstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
      lstatus.Text = "Invalid User Name or Password! Please try again!";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the code something like this:

```
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Email_ID  =  @Email AND Password = @Pass";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL,con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lemail.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lpwd.Text;
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            // bad logon
            lstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lstatus.Text = "Invalid User Name or Password! Please try again!";
            return;
        }

        // get here, we have a row of data, valid user + pass
        
        switch (dt.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString())
        {
            case "Rejected":

                lstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lstatus.Text = "your login id was rejected by admin";
                return;

            case "Pending":

                lstatus.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                lstatus.Text = "Your Login ID Is Pending";
                return;

            case "Approved":

                string strURL = "/WebPage/";
                switch (dt.Rows[0]["Role"].ToString())
                {
                    case "Admin": strURL += "Admin.aspx"; break;
                    case "Pilot": strURL += "Pilot.aspx"; break;
                    case "Stuff": strURL += "Staff.aspx"; break;
                }

                // we want that dialog prompt/message box BEFORE we navagate
                string myfunc = "alert('login Sucessful');window.location.href = '" + strURL + "';";

                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UpdateMessage", myfunc, true);
                break;
        }
```